# Need Array inside other Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

For some reason I need to push an Array inside other array.

For example,

```
var a = ["Test1", 1];
var b = ["Test2", 2];
var c = [];
c.push(a);
c.push(b);
alert(c);
```

For this code I need the following output,

```
["Test1", 1],["Test2", 2]
```

But what I am getting is

```
Test1,1,Test2,2
```

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Comment: By “output”, do you mean that you want to show that to a user or convert it to that string somehow, or just that you want your arrays’ structure to look like that? It’s already fine, but JavaScript joins arrays with `,` by default and adds nothing else. `["Test 1", 1]` gets turned into `"Test1,1"`, `["Test2", 2]` into `"Test2,2"`, and then they’re likewise combined with a comma to produce `Test1,1,Test2,2`. Try using `console.log`.

Comment: You're getting exactly what you want, but `alert()` is not a debugging tool, it converts the array to a string.

Comment: Use console.log() and you'll show the array good.

Comment: I want my `c` structure to look like that.

Comment: `console.log` would be the good alternative for debugging.

Comment: It already does look like that, but `alert()` is not able to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've already done it correctly: `c.push(a)` and `c.push(b)` work, but you don't want to use `alert()` for debugging.

Though it might be more convenient since you don't have to open up a console, it's going to give you output that is inconsistent with the actual structure of the data because using `alert(x)` converts whatever `x` is to a string.

*Always* use `console.log()`. Had you done that in  this case, you would have seen something like this in the console:

[image]

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/SRJf7/)

Comment: Okay friend, Got it, Thank you so much, Wait for a 4 minis, I will accept it.